# how to visualise DAE as ODE on manifold

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-algebraic-equations

In many papers and textbooks, there is always a brief comment that differential-algebraic equations (DAE) can be considered as a system of ordinary differential equation (ODE) on manifold. But then nowhere is it explained what it actually means.

I desperately want to see what does it mean and visualize that manifold. What are the necessary steps to do? Is the algebraic part defining some sort of manifold and if so, how?

Some (possibly schematic only) concrete example is much appreciated.

**Edit.** To keep things simple, lets focus only on index-1 DAEs as suggested in the comment.

**Edit2** Is it like the follwoing? For every (consistent) initial values, I have to find all solutions and the result is the manifold?
Is the resulting quite different from what I would get when DAE is further reduced do ODE?

Comment: This kind of visualization is actually only true for index-1 systems. Otherwise you get hidden constraints that are quite literally hidden in such a visualization. Take the simple pendulum as example, $\ddot x=\lambda x$, $\ddot y=-g+\lambda y$, $x^2+y^2=L^2$. So you have 3 dimensions and 3 equations, but to get something usable you need two derivatives of the constraint.

Comment: Honestly, I am that type of person who need more specific and step by step reasoning. To make this thread useful in future, a worked out example (almost) is desirable